# Stripping custom methods using python

Tags: python, porting

I am trying to port a bash script entirely to python.I am doing this as an attempt to take the plunge into python.

A part of the bash script deals with capturing sections depending on the regex .

This is how I did it in the bash script :

Search for the regex [multiline] Eg : `m/^[^\S\n]*\([\w0-9,*\s]*\)\s*\{[^\S\n]*\}/gm` //Not the actual regex !

Get the start line number of the above regex

Use `awk` to start reading from  the line number in a while loop . Scan each line searching for the method start ie `[` .Increment count variable if `[` is found otherwise if a `]` is encountered decrement the counter .If counter == 0 then print `NR` and exit the loop . This gave me the section end line nubmer.

Again I used `awk` to sngle out the section.
 `nawk  -v start=$var -v end=$var2 'NR >=start && NR <=end' file.sci`

Example file to be treated :

```
!!--Blah
!!
!!
method1 {fn->23}[          --line 12
     if [ ] ;else[]
 ]                         --line 14
method2 {fn->23,f2->65}[
     if [ ] ;else[i=0]
[[[[]]]] 
 ]
```

What the bashcript did was that it gave me the method1 start say line 12 then this start was give to the awk function which read line by line and kept a counter on `[` and `]` ,and at last gave line 14 for method 1 .Then using the line numbers I stripped out the methods in to another file .

I have done the regex part but I dont know if the approach with line number is feasible in python or not. I am sure that there exists better algorithm than the one mentioned .It would be appreciated if someone could  guide me in the right direction or provide a sample code or pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I'd do it in Python:

```
import re # to be able to use regular expressions
count = 0
found_one_at_least = False
result = ""
with open("read_file", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.search(regexp, line) is not None: # single line re to know when to start recording; returns None if there is no match, help(re.search) will tell you
            break # stop this loop and go on to the actual recording
    for line in f: # this will continue reading from where the last loop stopped, because it is an f is an iterator
        # to make it not do that you can use f.seek(0), but we do not need that
        result += line # append the line to the result
        count += line.count("[")-line.count("]") # compute the number of open/close brackets
        if count >= 1: # this is just so it does not stop at the first line if there is no [ in it
            found_one_at_least = True
        if count == 0 and found_one_at_least:
            break # stop recording when we are back at the "root" level
with open("write_file", "w") as f: # open the file, and let python handle closing and cleaning up...
    f.write(result) # write the result
```

I didn't really see the point of the regexp, because it seems like it won't match any line of your sample, but anyway, you could use whatever regexp you like, but remember that you are working on a line basis, so only single-line.

Also, as you'll be using the same regexp, you might want to do this:

```
regexp = re.compile(regexp_string)
# ...
if regexp.search(string) is not None:
# ...
```

It might give you a small performance boost.